# Kotlin enum constructor argument 'must be initialized' with companion object constant without qualifier name

Tags: kotlin, enums

This code compiles successfully with the qualified name used to access the constants from the companion object:

```
enum class CampsiteCategoryCode(val code: String) {
  TENT(CampsiteCategoryCode.TENT_CODE), // intellij says 'Redundant qualifier name'
  OTHER(CampsiteCategoryCode.OTHER_CODE), // intellij says 'Redundant qualifier name'
  LODGING(CampsiteCategoryCode.LODGING_CODE), // intellij says 'Redundant qualifier name'
  RV(CampsiteCategoryCode.RV_CODE); // intellij says 'Redundant qualifier name'

  override fun toString() = code

  companion object {
    const val TENT_CODE = "tent"
    const val OTHER_CODE = "other"
    const val LODGING_CODE = "lodging"
    const val RV_CODE = "rv"
  }
}
```

However, the same code without the qualifier name fails compilation:

```
enum class CampsiteCategoryCode(val code: String) {
  TENT(TENT_CODE), // Variable 'TENT_CODE' must be initialized
  OTHER(OTHER_CODE), // Variable 'OTHER_CODE' must be initialized
  LODGING(LODGING_CODE), // Variable 'LODGING_CODE' must be initialized
  RV(RV_CODE); // Variable 'RV_CODE' must be initialized

  override fun toString() = code

  companion object {
    const val TENT_CODE = "tent"
    const val OTHER_CODE = "other"
    const val LODGING_CODE = "lodging"
    const val RV_CODE = "rv"
  }
}
```

Why does specifying the qualifier name allow this code to compile? Or put another way, why does *not* having the qualifier name make the code fail to compile?

Comment: While it's a good question, I don't see why you need companion object at all in your case. What's wrong with `TENT("tent")`?

Comment: @dyukha I need to interpolate the code in annotation strings, and they need to be compile time constants. I tried the way you are suggesting before I resorted to this method.

Comment: btw you can declare these constants on the file level like this https://pl.kotl.in/48uHeStGH

Answer (score 14):

That `companion object` will be instantiated the moment your class becomes available (compile time). Then you are telling your class that, for it to become available, it needs a class that is not yet available (because you're compiling it at the moment and, apparently, Kotlin makes enum cases available before companion objects)

I can't tell for sure if this is intended from Kotlin, but  to avoid this kind of cases, declare your constants outside this class

Comment: This is an extremely important distinction. I have been struggling for days on this without an understanding of why. ty ty ty

Comment: for more than one constant an object works too, like: object MyConstants { const val FOO = "foo" const val BAR = "bar" } - available both from the enum entry declarations & annotations

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions for that:

1. make the variable a top-level declaration (as @baguIO mentioned)
2. mention the scope explicitly (use `CampsiteCategoryCode.TENT_CODE` instead of just `TENT_CODE`)

Comment: Adding the scope explicitly seems to please the compiler but fails at runtime for me when trying to call a method with: `ExceptionInInitializerError` ... `at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach` ... `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` of the method defined on the companion  I'm trying to call.

Comment: Using option number two causes a warning to appear: `Companion object of enum class 'CampsiteCategoryCode' is uninitialized here. This warning will become an error in future releases. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49110 for details`